# Send email from IBM Notes with attachment

Tags: excel, vba, email, lotus-notes, attachment

I'd like to send an email with an attachment using VBA and Lotus Notes. I manage to send an email but the attachment is never included. What am I missing here?

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim fromAdr As String
    Dim subject As String
    Dim recip As String
    Dim numSend As Integer
    Dim Attachment1 As String

    ' Mail settings
    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields

    ' Mail fields
    fromAdr = """example@example.com"
    recip = """example@example.com"
    Debug.Print strbody
    subject = "Orders fondsen"
    strbody = strbody & "Hi," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Please find the document..."

    ' Fields layout
    strbody = strbody & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Text"
    Debug.Print strbody
    strbody = strbody & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind regards,"

    ' Location attachment
    Attachment1 = "file-path"

    ' send mail
    On Error GoTo handleError
    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = recip
        .CC = ""
        .From = fromAdr
        .subject = subject
        .TextBody = strbody
        .Send
    End With
    numSend = numSend + 1
    GoTo skipError

handleError:
    numErr = numErr + 1
    oFile.WriteLine "*** ERROR *** Email for account" & " not sent. Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
skipError:

    On Error GoTo 0

    MsgBox "Total number of emails send: " & numSend & vbNewLine & "Total number of errors: " & numErr, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Operation finished"
    GoTo endProgram
cancelProgram:
    MsgBox "No emails have been sent.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Operation cancelled"

endProgram:
    Application.Interactive = True
    Set iMsg = Nothing
    Set iConf = Nothing
    Set dp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the attachment :

```
With iMsg
   Set .Configuration = iConf
   .To = recip
   .CC = ""
   .From = fromAdr
   .subject = subject
   .TextBody = strbody
   .AddAttachment Attachment1 
   .Send
End With
```

You can repeat the `.AddAttachment` for each attachment you want to add.

Comment: I don't know how I could forget that part. Guess it's time for a break... Thanks!